# How to display the output of command which run in machine Y.and program is written in machine X?

Tags: linux

I have two Linux Machine,1st is machine X ,other is machine Y i want to write a java program which will run in machine X..eq test.java ..and when i run that java program it should ask for login credential of machine Y and will execute some command for example
ls -l in machine Y automatically after login. and it should display the output of ls -l 
in machine X.
How to do it please help me????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use java for this. This can be easily done by using [SSH](http://support.suso.com/supki/SSH_Tutorial_for_Linux) i.e.

```
$ssh user@server <command>
```

If you are running this command on machine X

```
[user@X~]$ ssh user@Y 'ls -l'
password:

total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 user group 4096 Apr 13 21:19 fooo
drwxr-xr-x 3 user group 4096 Jun 17  2009 bar
```

Comment: ya you are corect but how ..to display the output of machine Y in machine X...plz tell me??

Comment: I have edited my answer. If you run this command on machine X and ssh to machine Y, it will display the output on machine X only.

Comment: Also, don't forgot to accept the answer which works for you. It will motivate other peoples to provide you better solutions.

Answer (score 1):

No need to write a program, use ssh. This will of course require that a ssh server is running on machine Y, but you will need some kind of server to implement this anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like xmlrpc client/server relationship, can make things a little easier if this is going to scale significantly.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/j-xmlrpc.html

for an example.